# counting values in two columns at the same time? SQL/SQLITE

Tags: sql, sqlite

The problem I am attemping to do is find which two people go on the most number of trips together. I created a table where you have the name of a person, the name of somebody that went on a hike with them, the name of the peak, and the date. I want to be able to count all of the values of name1 and name2. Ex in my dataset below I want to count how many times 'Mary' and 'Patricia' appear side by side. I tried to use a COUNT(name1,name2) as numPairs and using group by (name1,name2) but SQLLITE says count() can only take in one parameter.

If my query looks off it is mainly due to the fact I am more comfortable using relational algebra selections/projections to get my data. am open to any other solutions that may help me
[image]

mary,patricia

brad,steven

cherry,rick

brad,steven

mary,patricia

mary,patricia
| 2

brad,steven  | 2

cherry,rick  | 1

Comment: please paste the data as insert statement in text so it can be reused , also paste your desired output

Comment: You are querying 2 tables, right? Post sample data of both tables and expected results to clarify.

Comment: I edited an example into submission. The dataset is a big file and a hassle to post. I just need to be able to use count() on two variables

Comment: Sample data is not your actual database. Take some time to post a few rows of each of the tables involved in text tabular format and not images. Also your expected result in text tabular format so we can understand the requirement. As you can see you already received 2 answers which I believe don't solve your problem because their code are based on guessing what you have and what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply want aggregation?

```
select name1, name2, count(*) 
from t
group by name1, name2;
```

If you want distinct pairs, so the ordering doesn't matter, you can use `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
select least(name1, name2), greatest(name1, name2), count(*) 
from t
group by least(name1, name2), greatest(name1, name2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nested query as below

```
select count(*) as Num_of_times,both_names, peak1 from (select concat(name1,",",name2) 
as both_names, peak1 from your_table) as tbl group by both_names;
```